# AMPScript LookUp in ExactTarget/Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud

```
%%[
    for @currentrow = 1 to RowCount(@Rows) do
        SET @row = Row(@Rows, @currentrow)
        SET @Item Field(@row, "Product_Name") // This line has an error
]%%
        <BR> %%=v(@item)=%%
%%[
    next @currentrow
]%%
```

When we try to put the line `SET @Item Field(@row, "Product_Name")` it is saved but the I am unable to publish it.  It's throwing an error. `Product_Name` is a valid field as text.

Any insights? How can i check the log?

Comment: Where are you setting `@rows`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `=` sign on the `SET`

```
SET @Item = Field(@row, "Product_Name") // Now it shouldn't have an error
```